# Android migration to appcompat v7 causes error: Attribute "color" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I recently decided to include the `appcompat-v7` library in my app, so as to have support for material design, and also use the newer `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, since the one in `support-v4` has been deprecated.

My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to `23`. The versions for both `support-v4` and `appcompat-v7` are set to `23.1.0`.

However, as soon as I did a sync on my project, I ran into the following error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"color\" has already been
>   defined","sources":[{"file":"/Users/work/source/android/app.android.whitelabel/WhiteLabelApp/src/main/res/values/config.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}

Looking around, I discovered that many have encountered similar issues with different versions of appcompat library. And I also understand, that this error indicates there is some `color` value in my `config.xml` file which is conflicting with some other file. But, as of now, the error doesn't provide me with any clue as to which particular `color` attribute is conflicting. My `config.xml` file also has many such project specific `color` attributes defined.

If I remove the `appcompat-v7` library, this error disappears.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in this particular case, the root problem ended up being that the `attrs.xml` file under the `values` folder had a custom tag defined, which unfortunately was named as `color`. This was some legacy definition, which wasn't even used anymore.

Somehow, incorporating the `appcompat-v7` library triggered the error (wonder why `support-v4` didn't!).

What made the situation frustrating and misleading was that `gradle` pointed the error being in the `config.xml`, whereas it was in the `attrs.xml` file!

At the end, the slow and tedious approach of copying my `res` files one at a time into a new project structure revealed where the real problem lied.

Thanks *@Timo* for patiently trying to help me out here!

Answer (score 1):

First try to delete that colors from the config.xml

Did you define anywhere else colors in a xml file? (Yes? -> delete it)

This seems to be a referencing problem.

Comment: Removing every single instance of `color` from all XML files seems like a brute force hack to this problem. My app makes use of variants, of which there are currently 23. There is a `config.xml` file for each variant. Even when I've removed all the instances of `color` from the current variant's `config.xml` file, the error *still* persists.

I even created a brand new project and copied the same `config.xml` file, without deleting the `color` attributes – and that project compiled/built just fine.

Comment: The most frustrating thing here is that Android isn't even telling me which particular `color` reference is in conflict!

Comment: Sometimes all problems got solved by creating a new project and copy all files from the old in there. Else you have to try this "brute force" thing.